# Edit Mode is not available

Tags: edit-mode

I imported a model from the "Blender-Kit" Addon, but there´s only Object mode available. There´s also no "Material" Propertie on the right side... Is it possible to fix this, or can´t be Models from Blender-Kit edited?[image: Interface without Edit Mode or Material Propertie---> Version 2.8]

Comment: is it a linked object? in that case select it and go in the Object menu > Relations > Make Local > Selected Object, Data and Materials

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a mesh Object. It'a `Collection Instance` : an empty.

You can run the command `Make Instances Real` to create the instanced mesh Objects. Then you can edit them

Answer (score 0):

I think blender kit objects will come in collections, try to select individual objects/single object from collection and then try for toggling edit mode - object mode